# Homework help needed java interface using MyMath

Tags: java, interface

Aright, I think i got this going. But now I'm having an issue with the interface methods. The interface method uses a generic type  and 1 object. But the assignment calls for adding two  objects. I'm now stuck at this point. I'm not sure how to write the add(T o) interface since I can only send one object into the method. I've tried using value1.add(value2) but when I test the values only values for values1 seems to come up. I have no idea where value2 goes Here is my class and the interface

```
public class MyFraction implements MyMath<MyFraction> {
private List<Character> sign = new ArrayList<Character>();
private List<Integer> numerator = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<Integer> denominator = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public MyFraction(int numerator, int denominator, char sign) {
    this.numerator.add(numerator);
    this.denominator.add(denominator);
    this.sign.add(sign);

}
public MyFraction(){}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFraction run = new MyFraction();
    run.start();
}

private void start() {
    char sign = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter - for negative + for positive number ").charAt(0);
    int numerator = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a numerator ")));
    int denominator = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a denominator ")));
    MyFraction value1 = new MyFraction(numerator, denominator, sign);

    sign = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter - for negative + for positive number ").charAt(0);
    numerator = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a numerator ")));
    denominator = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a denominator ")));
    MyFraction value2 = new MyFraction(numerator, denominator, sign);

    System.out.println("numerator 1: "+value1.getNumerator() );
    System.out.println("denominator 1: "+value1.getDenominator() );
    System.out.println("sign 1: "+value1.getSign() );
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("numerator 2: "+value2.getNumerator() );
    System.out.println("denominator 2: "+value2.getDenominator() );
    System.out.println("sign 2: "+value2.getSign() );
}


public int getNumerator(){
    int value = this.numerator.get(0);
    return value;
}
public int getDenominator(){
    int value =  this.denominator.get(0);
            return value;
}
public char getSign(){
    char value = this.sign.get(0);
    return value;
}


@Override
public MyFraction add(MyFraction o) {

    return null;
}
@Override
public MyFraction subtract(MyFraction o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public MyFraction divide(MyFraction o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public MyFraction multiply(MyFraction o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

```
public interface MyMath<T> {
public T add(T o);

public T subtract(T o);

public T divide(T o);

public T multiply(T o);
```

}

Comment: An interface is just like a skeleton.It says how the design of your classes should be if you implement that interface which helps in keeping the code clean and maintainable.Note that logic comes in the class and you need to implement all of the mentioned methods in your interface

Answer (score 1):

An `interface` is somewhat a contract, that sais "whoever implements me **must** contain an implementation of **all** the methods declared in me". Every `class` that `implements` that `interface` figuratevely signs that contract and therefore must have it's **own** implementation of these methods.

In your class you are missing the implementation of the **whole** interface, which is why your code is not compiling. Your class should look like:

```
public class MyFraction implements MyMath<MyFraction> {
....

}
//interface memebers
@Override
public MyFraction subtract(MyFraction o){
   //do subtraction here
   return null;
}

@Override
public MyFraction divide(MyFraction o){
   //do division here
   return null;
}

@Override
public MyFraction multiply(MyFraction o){
   //do multiplication here
   return null;
}

@Override
public MyFraction add(MyFraction o) {
    // do adding here
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Ya, I know that I deleted the code since the methods were empty. Probably should have posted the full code. I read the book and know what rules interfaces use. I know interface methods are all public, static and variables are final. And I know whichever class uses the interface must use all methods in the interface.

Comment: The book goes kinda backwards from this assignment letting the interface have code and the class just send in information to the code and return some value. In this assignment its backwards and this is where im stuck. From my understanding the MyMath uses T as an object and I'm not sure how to .. Dont know how to put it but link the interface to my class.

Comment: If the books sais the interface can have an implementation of the methods, you are probably reading a book about java 8 (where **default** methods exist). Java 8 is not officially released.

Comment: Alright I just rewrote my code, and created two MyFraction objects. Now I'm still stuck trying to override the interface. For example the add() takes in 1 object so how am I suppose to add both objects if the interface only takes in 1 object?

Comment: @user3350193 The first MyFraction object is the current instance of the MyFraction class (`this`) and the second is the `o` parameter (`o` is short for `other`).

Comment: Alright I see what you mean. I'm gonna do some reading and figure this out. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please take a step back and think about the solution you got so far. Your class `MyFraction` contains four lists - why? "My" `MyFraction` would consist of a numerator, a denominator and maybe a sign.

Would I choose a `Character` to store the sign-> I do not know. But you should think about negative values for the numerator and denominator, e.g. numerator is -4 and denominator -2. What value has `MyFraction` when the sign is entered as "-".

To create a `MyFraction` instance you should be able to use a constructor like this

```
public MyFraction(Integer theNumerator, Integer theDenominator, Character theSign)
```

And remember to implement all methods of the interface. You got only the method `add` so far and code will not compile because of the missing implementations.

Comment: The assignment calls for a char to hold the sign. The reason why I made the fourth list is because im trying to somehow make the objects work with the interface since the methods given from that interface use objects. This maybe why im stuck

Comment: @user3350193 You are probably confuse by the <T> part. These are generics, which you can read up here -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Comment: The methods in the interface use objects of class T (generics), right. In your implementation those objects are of type MyFraction - there is imo no need for lists.

Comment: @Mario, Ya the <T> is probably whats confusing me. I'm gonna go through the book for generics. Thanks for the help man i think this will solve my problem, hopefully lol